# Protect Google API Key Used in Public WP Plugin

Tags: wordpress, google-search-console

Good Day Everyone,

I am planning to build a WP plugin that needs Google Search Console API. The goal is to not ship my API Key and Client ID along with the plugin.

1. WP Plugin -> requests data from domain.com
2. domain.com requests data from Google Search Console API
3. domain.com sends data to WP Plugin without saving it
4. WP Plugin saves the data localy where it is installed

May I know if this is possible and what I need to do please?

Thanks,

EDIT:16Feb

I found out that this can be done by authenticating users from the client side (wp plugin)

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new Google_Client();

$client->setScopes( array( 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters.readonly' ) );
$client->setAccessType( 'offline' );
$client->setRedirectUri( 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob' );
$client->setClientId( '302343592020-r7ouc9s9jaukc54j48s3k9fg26eeiaqr.apps.googleusercontent.com' );
$client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);

//Generate access code from the link below
//echo '<a href="'.$client->createAuthUrl().'" target="_blank">Access Code</a>';

$code = '###############';

$client->authenticate($code); $access_token = $client->getAccessToken();
```

however, the access token is empty

Answer (score 0):

I start with an assumption: domain.com has API available and is also WordPress.

(domain.com) You should create a custom REST API endpoint with POST or GET method (really up to you how to handle and authorize the request - I would use POST as the request can be validated on domain.com, for example, domainX.com is whitelisted and can access the API key).

WordPress API reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/

WordPress API guide: https://kinsta.com/blog/wordpress-rest-api/

In the plugin, you will make the POST request to the domain.com and pass something in the body - something like URL maybe (really up to you). You should also use Authentication.
The domain.com will receive the request, process it and it will return the API key in the response. From there it's down the hill all the way :)

Let me know if this makes sense - I could post some code for this but there are so many different ways of making this...

Comment: hello Fresz, thank you for the reply.. I edited my question to show how I attempt to address the issue. But i am still stuck at getting the access token. I've seen some plugins where they only need users to accept the consent and they get authenticated and can request data from Google API. Do you know if i missed something in my code? thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I will mark this question solved.

I came to realize that WP Plugin can authenticate through the my domain to get access token. Then use the access token to make calls directly from wp_plugin to google api.

This way I wont be shipping my client secret along with the plugin source code.

Answer (score -2):

If you’re asking how to conceal your Google API key, you can use a file called .env

DO NOT PUT ANYTHING BEFORE THE DOT

In here, you can put a variable and you can pull it to python (might need to create a new file and pull it to whichever language you’re using.

You can use this code to use it.

Here is the guide: https://docs.repl.it/repls/secret-keys